# Make symlink laravel public folder

Tags: laravel, server, symlink

i've tried push my laravel 5.1 project to server. I want to make a symlink to public_html folder so i can access it like normal.

```
ln -sv app/crowd/public public_html
```

i've tried that one. but the symlink is taking the public folder instead of it's content.

```
ln -sv ~/app/crowd/public ~/public_html
```

i've tried that one too but it still fail.

any suggestion how to make it works?

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the public folder instead of it's content"?

Answer (score 0):

If "the symlink is taking the public folder instead of it's content" means that your browser is giving a 403 or saying you can't access the folder, it may mean that you don't have `index.php` in your DirectoryIndex directive (if you're using Apache - not sure what the equivalent is on nginx).

When you enter a location in your browser and don't include a filename (`www.host.com/page.html`), the server looks at a list of default pages and sees if one of those is present.  If not, it tries to serve the whole directory.  Try browsing to `www.host.com/index.php` and see what you get. If it loads, you just need to update your config. If not, please explain what you see.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ln -s public public_html
```